# how to send data from js to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send data from js to a php function, then I want to return the function result in a div, here is my code:

```
function loadpage(){
    var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.php',
        data: {'text': text},
        success: function(){
            $("#inneroutput").load("lib/ajax.php");
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<textarea placeholder="Type your text here..."
id="textarea"></textarea> <div id="inneroutput"></div>
```

ajax.php :

> `<?php
>     $data = $_POST['text'];
>
>   echo $data; ?>`

but I got an error in php:

```
Undefined index: text
```

so where is the error in my code?

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML, as well.

Comment: Where do you get that error? JS or PHP? What's in lib/ajax.php?

Comment: Why are you running two distinct ajax

Comment: is the element's ID really "textarea"?

Comment: The `success` callback should include some kind of `data` parameter that you then append to the DOM.

Comment: how are you calling `loadpage` function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once!!

```
function loadpage(){ 
                //only for one textarea            
                var text = document.getElementByTagName("textarea").value;
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'lib/ajax.php',
                  data: {'data1': text},
                  success: function(res){
                          $("#inneroutput").html(res);
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the success of your first call.

```
$("#inneroutput").load("lib/ajax.php");
```

This calls the page again, only without your "text" parameter. ie - text is Undefined.

Change your success as mentioned below to:

```
success: function(res){
    $("#inneroutput").html(res);
}
```

Whatever you "echo" will come through in the "res" variable.

Comment: this is right, so how I can return the php results without recalling the php page?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the page `lib/ajax.php` twice.  Once you pass it a `$_POST` variable called 'text'.  The next time you do not.

I suspect that in your php file you are doing something with `$_POST['text']` without checking that it exists.  The second time you try to retrieve the page (without POSTing anything) it fails and you get this error.

Comment: I believe that this exactly answers the question "where is the error in my code".